# Changing symbology of group of layer from a list of symbology layers with Arcpy?

Tags: arcpy, symbology, list

I'm using arcpy to create a GUI in Arcmap that can import features and apply symbology with importing a list of symbology layers, but it doesn't work and without an error message.

```
    for x in range (0, (len(list2))):
          print('shp', list2[x])
          print('symb', list3[x])
          arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(list2[x] , list3[x]) 
    arcpy.RefreshTOC()
```

list2: layers to apply symbology; 
list3: symbology layers

This is my code:

```
# Set outWorkspace
outWorkspace = r'c:\Users\HAIDRA\Documents\Desktop\essai'
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("current")
style = askdirectory ()
styl_path.set(style)
# set the workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = style 
symbology_layers = arcpy.ListFiles("*")
print ('le premier boucle symbology_layers', symbology_layers)
list3=[]
print('list3', list3)
list3.append(symbology_layers)
print ('list3', list3)
dfs = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
lyrs = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", dfs)
print ('lyrs', lyrs)
list2=[]
print('list2', list2)
list2.append(lyrs)
print ('list2', list2)
for x in range (0, (len(list2))):
    print('shp', list2[x])
    print('symb', list3[x])
    arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(list2[x] , list3[x]) 
# Refresh the Table of Contents to reflect the change
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
```

Comment: How are `list2` and `list3` created?

Comment: For list2, i listed layers existing in my mxd and i insert them in a list (with list2.append(lyrs)). And for the other list, the same thing, but symbology layers are existing in a folder that i opened it

Comment: And could you show your code for this? It's difficult to find what's wrong without seeing it

Comment: How can i insert a code in a comment please?

Comment: Add it to your question

Comment: Ok, i added it   in the question

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create `list2` and `list`3, instead you can use `lyrs` and `symbology_layers`, respectively.

When using append, you add one new item to a list, so your list variable will contain only one item (a list):

```
list2 = [[lyrs[0], lyrs[1], ... [lyrs[x]]
```

Appending is not necessary since the result of the list functions is already a list.

I would personnaly use [arcpy.mapping.UpdateLayer()](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/updatelayer.htm) to do what you're trying to do:

```
for x in range (0, (len(symbology_layers))):
    arcpy.mapping.UpdateLayer(dfs, lyrs[x], arcpy.mapping.Layer(symbology_layers[x]), 1)
```

**EDIT**

Another equivalent option, if you want to match layers based on their name (if corresponding layers have the same basename but a different extension) instead of their index in the list:

```
for x in lyrs:
    lyrname = x.name.split(".")[0]
    arcpy.mapping.UpdateLayer(dfs, x, arcpy.mapping.Layer(lyrname + ".lyr"), 1)
```

Comment: But it doesn't work too when i don't use list

Comment: Ok, i'll try it

Comment: It's work, but only to the first layer

Comment: Makes sense, there was an error in my code, I've fixed it: replace `symbology_layers[0]` with `symbology_layers[x]`

Comment: Yes,i try it, and it gives me the same result

Comment: Is the symbology from each `symbology_layers` item compatible with the symbology from the corresponding `lyrs` item? Are they iterated in the right order? Add some print statements to understand what's going on. If the code works for the first layer it must be a data issue, not a code issue

Comment: Those are my layers: [<map layer u'puits.shp_lyr'>, <map layer u'mosquet.shp_lyr'>, <map layer u'mine.shp_lyr'>, <map layer u'marabout.shp_lyr'>].   And my symbology layers: [u'marabout.lyr', u'mine.lyr', u'mosquet.lyr', u'puits.lyr']. How can i order them? Sorry i'm beginner in python language

Comment: That would be a separate question... to make it simple let's use the layers' name since in your case they are the same, see edit.

Comment: No, it gives no result

Comment: i didn't found any solution